# Sitemap: submitting multiple URLs for dynamic content

Tags: javascript, dynamic, sitemap

Let's take a website where all content is loaded onto a single page. Most content is hidden by `<div style="display:none">`, but is rendered visible by javaScript when the user clicks certain elements.

However, as not all people use javaScript the content can also be rendered visible on page reload thanks to PHP. Like so: www.example.com/content1.php or www.example.com/content2.php.

E.g. clicking the first link would return: `<div class="content1" style="display:inline">We provide banking services</div><div class="content2" style="display:none">We also make great hot-dogs.</div>`

conversely clicking the second link would return:
`<div class="content1" style="display:none">We provide banking services</div><div class="content2" style="display:inline">We also make great hot-dogs.</div>`

So, with other words all content is always loaded onto the page. Considering search engine crawlers, should I include both URLs in the Sitemap document or would this be considered 'cheating' the search engines? Like so:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"> 
   <url> 
      <loc>http://www.example.com/content1.php</loc> 
      <lastmod>2008-01-01</lastmod> 
      <changefreq>weekly</changefreq> 
      <priority>1.0</priority> 
   </url> 
   <url> 
      <loc>http://www.example.com/content2.php</loc> 
      <changefreq>weekly</changefreq> 
      <priority>0.5</priority>
   </url>
</urlset>
```

Or does it even matter for SEO and, perhaps more to the point, what snippets are visible in the search results?

If someone out there happens to be really into this stuff, what if there is a named anchor tag where the content is displayed on the site? Would it be appropriate then to include hash tags in the Sitemap document, like so:

```
<loc>http://www.example.com/content1.php#services</loc>
```

Comment: I know that in 2006 BMW was [removed from Googles index](http://www.dw.de/google-removes-bmws-german-web-site-from-search-index/a-1894465) for having white links on top of a white div. So you should atleast be carefull

Comment: I know... That's what I was thinking about...